# Gulpfile: How to compile each SCSS into separate CSS with same name but with additional common styles

Tags: css, sass, gulp

First of all I'd like you guys to be gentle. I haven't been coding much in recent year and since gulp update when then changed syntax to writing functions and exporting I somehow made it work then and left with no changes up to this point, no clue if they changed something else. I've been happy with what it is right now, but I have no idea how to make it work the other way.

So anyway I'm working on a project right now, where there will be many htmls, and each one will have quite different styles, but some will be common. I want to make a main.scss file with common styles for each html, but I want to make a separate scss with styles specific to each html. This way in the end I want to have a separate css file made from a specific scss with same name combined with main.scss, so that it won't have to download a single large file, but only styles I need.

Example:

```
main.scss
01.scss
02.scss
03.scss
```

will compile to:

```
01.css ( main.scss + 01.scss )
02.css ( main.scss + 02.scss )
03.css ( main.scss + 03.scss )
```

This is my gulpfile right now:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const sass = require('gulp-sass');
const browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

function style() {
  return gulp.src('./scss/**/*.scss')
   .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
   .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'))
   .pipe(browserSync.stream());
}

function watch() {
  browserSync.init({
    server: {
      baseDir: './'
    }
  });
  gulp.watch('./scss/**/*.scss', style);
  gulp.watch('./*.html').on('change', browserSync.reload);
  gulp.watch('./js/**/*.js').on('change', browserSync.reload);
}

exports.style = style;
exports.watch = watch;
```

If you have an idea how to do it in a better way I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will have to import your `main.scss` into each of your other files and exclude `main.scss` from your `gulp.src`.

```
function style() {
  return gulp.src(['./scss/**/*.scss', '!./scss/**/main.scss'])

  .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'))
  .pipe(browserSync.stream());
}
```

`'!./scss/**/main.scss'` this negates or excludes that file from being passes into this task - I assumed `main.scss` was in the same folder as your other `scss` files, if that is not the case you will have to modify the path.

Then `@import` `main.scss` into each of your `01.scss`, `02.scss`, etc. files:

`@import "main.scss";`  // also assumes in same folder

You can put this import statement anywhere in the file, if it is first any of `main.scss` styles will be overridden by conflicting styles in the rest of the `0x.scss` file.  If you put the import statement at the end, then `main.scss` styles will override any previous conflicting styles.

---

Note: you should really be using `@use` instead of `@import`  and [gulp-dart-sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-dart-sass) instead of `gulp-sass` at this point.  See [sass @use rule](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use).

`// in your gulpfile.js`
`const sass = require('gulp-dart-sass');`  // once installed

`@use "main.scss";`  // must be at top of each scss file, such as 01.scss

Comment: I was doing some coding meanwhile waiting for someone to answer my question and have found out that it actually keeps every file separatelly rather than combining them into one, so yeah, it was really easier than I thought since I already use "@import". Thank you very much for updating me tho! I've changed to dart-sass already, but will need a bit of reading on "@use", cause that doesnt work right now, don't know why - tried with underscore and without, with .scss and without, tried changing names thinking "main" might be reserved word but still nothing. Will figure it out in next project :)